# ProgressIndicator transparent background

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

So I have this code:

```
    final StackPane g = new StackPane();        
    final ProgressIndicator p1 = new ProgressIndicator();
    p1.setPrefSize(100, 100);  
    p1.progressProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") 
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Number oldVal, Number newVal) {

            if (p1.getProgress() < 0.3) {
                p1.setStyle("-fx-progress-color: red;");
            } else if (p1.getProgress() < 0.65) {
                p1.setStyle("-fx-progress-color: orange;");
            } else {
                p1.setStyle("-fx-progress-color: green;");
            }

        }
    });
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.setAutoReverse(true);

    final KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(p1.progressProperty(), 1);
    final KeyFrame kf1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(3000), kv);
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf1);


    g.getChildren().addAll(p1); //veil
    g.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

Then I add the stack pane to a scene and the scene to the stage.

I have two stages, the initial stage with all my things and this additional stage with the progress indicator. Here is the problem: the stage that contains the progress indicator has a white squared(box) as background that fits perfect to the other stage, because usually has the same white background. But when the initial background is not white I can see the white background of the progress indicator stage. So here is my question: **How can I make this background transparent?** I tried the BlendMode class, but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use an external style sheet with

```
.progress-indicator .indicator {
    -fx-background-color: transparent ;
}
```

Here's a complete example (I used the external style sheet to manage the colors too, but this will work anyway):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ProgressIndicatorTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();
        Task<Void> counter = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                    updateProgress(i, 100);
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        pi.progressProperty().bind(counter.progressProperty());
        pi.progressProperty().addListener((obs, oldProgress, newProgress) -> {
            PseudoClass warning = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("warning");
            PseudoClass critical = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("critical");
            if (newProgress.doubleValue() < 0.3) {
                pi.pseudoClassStateChanged(warning, false);
                pi.pseudoClassStateChanged(critical, true);
            } else if (newProgress.doubleValue() < 0.65) {
                pi.pseudoClassStateChanged(warning, true);
                pi.pseudoClassStateChanged(critical, false);
            } else {
                pi.pseudoClassStateChanged(warning, false);
                pi.pseudoClassStateChanged(critical, false);
            }
        });
        pi.setMaxSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: antiqueWhite;");
        root.getChildren().add(pi);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("progress.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        new Thread(counter).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

progress.css:

```
.progress-indicator .indicator {
    -fx-background-color: transparent ;
}
.progress-indicator {
    -fx-progress-color: green ;
}
.progress-indicator:critical {
    -fx-progress-color: red ;
}
.progress-indicator:warning {
    -fx-progress-color: orange ;
}
```

Comment: I tried that and doesn't work, I still have the white box. I think should be something with setting the clip.

Comment: Works fine for me. Updated with an example. If that doesn't work, try using [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) to see where the white box is coming from (maybe it's from your stack pane, for example).

Comment: Actually it was from the stack pane, when I changed that to Group, it worked. Plus I added the parameter "Color.Transparent" to the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for css (based on a bugfix for Java 8u40):

```
.progress-indicator:indeterminate > .spinner {
    /** Applying to undo styling from .spinner, reported in RT-37965 */
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the above answers worked.

I finally got it working by:

```
progressIndicator.getScene().getRoot().setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
```

If you are using a scene, make the scene transparent by also doing:

```
scene.setFill(null);
```